# How do I make multiple columns in SUM statement into a single statement in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have something like this in my Query:

```
SUM(cb.MerchandiseSales + 
    cb.MerchandiseSalesTax +
    cb.MerchandiseReturns + 
    cb.MerchandiseReturnsTax + 
    cb.OtherSales + 
    cb.OtherSalesTax + 
    cb.GiftCSold + 
    cb.StoreCreditIssued + 
    cb.DepositReceived)         AS TotalSales,
```

Above is one of the columns in my query I have many like this in my query?
I want to do something like: 
`SUM(@totalSales)`
where

```
@totalSales =   cb.MerchandiseSales + 
    cb.MerchandiseSalesTax +
    cb.MerchandiseReturns + 
    cb.MerchandiseReturnsTax + 
    cb.OtherSales + 
    cb.OtherSalesTax + 
    cb.GiftCSold + 
    cb.StoreCreditIssued + 
    cb.DepositReceived
```

All are `NUMERIC(19,4)`

I am unable to achieve this because my Query has a Group by expression.
Please advice.

Comment: You could get many answers but you solution will be the fastest one, it's ugly but fast.

Answer (score 0):

GROUPING SETS - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008/

In T-SQL you will have something like this:

```
GROUP BY GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
    (col1, col2, etc.) -- columns you using in your GROUP BY now
    ,()                -- grand Total
)
```